# Why would my passenger door be filling with water?

Tags: door, seal, water, titan

Nissan Titan 2012 model the passenger side front door continues to fill with water even when it doesn't rain. Per research if the floor board was wet on the passenger side it would be a clogged drain however the floor board is dry.

When I research to see if the door has a drain I'm unable to find any results. When reviewing the seals they look to be fine, no damage and door has never been wrecked per my understanding and just has started doing it within last month.

What would cause the door to fill with water and what should I do resolve it? Is this a standard issue and I just have a clogged drain in the door?

When you open the door you can hear it swoosh around. After opening and swinging water will slowly leak out. Hope that helps because I've been unsuccessful in finding any results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps the next Titan owner. Actually the door doesn't have a drain but a seal strip. This is barely in place and after taking a shop towel and cleaning the gunk and buildup did it resolve the issue. Pictured below are the schematics of the seal strip with links in case you need to replace yours:

actual strip for Armada but same part:

[image]

part number 6:

[image]

[site reference](https://www.getoemparts.com/oem-parts/nissan-surround-weather-strip-828308s500)

be for warned, not a good idea to clean it in the garage because gunk and water will go everywhere. Best to possibly do it on the driveway. Happy wife happy life, bad mistake will be your fate.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with that exact vehicle, but doors do, generally, have drains. Lay on the ground under the open door and look for small holes. Poke up through the holes with a toothpick or something similar to see if anything comes out.

The drains are generally closer to the exterior side of the door.

Water enters doors around the window and any other piercings in the door. Most are sealed, but seals do fail.

Why/how this would fill up with no rain, is a mystery. Do you wash your car a lot?

If all else fails, you can take the interior door panel off and see if there is a lot of junk at the bottom of your doors. Pine needles, in particular, have a way of infiltrating unexpected places.

Answer (score 1):

That used to be a very common problem. The drains ( a rubber stopper) were usually hidden by the rubber weather stripping on the bottom of the door. When I found them I cut away the rubber as a tiny air leak is much less problem than a door full of water.  I had 2004 Titan , no water problems in 140,000 miles and it was parked outside under pines, oaks and several other kinds of trees.